# How do I convert from the global coordinate space to a local space?

Tags: 2d, mathematics, coordinates

Given an entity named `EntityA`, I want to define a local coordinate space, where the position of `EntityA` is the origin, its heading vector is the X axis, and the normal of the heading vector is the Y axis:

[image: pictorial description of the same]

Given their global coordinates, how do I find the position of another entity in `EntityA`'s local space?

An example: `EntityA`'s global position is (50,50), and that of `EntityB` is (80,90). What is then the position of `EntityB` in `EntityA`'s local space?

EDIT: Please go easy on the math.

Answer (score 21):

Okay, so
Assuming that you know what the World Transformation matrix for that object A is, You just need to construct the inverse of that matrix and you will have what you need.

Suppose the rotation, scaling and translation matrices of object A used to get it to Global Space are **R**, **S** and **T** respectively. You will multiply these together like

**S** * **R** * **T** = **W**

Now, take **W** and find its inverse **W^-1** somehow. The inverse of a matrix is that matrix which does just the opposite. The product of the matrix with its inverse is always the identity matrix.

**W** * **W^-1** = **I**

thus **W^-1** = **I** / **W**;

Now Apply this inverse matrix as the world transformation to the scene and each object will be in the coordinates you wanted.

For matrix multiplication, see [This page.](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)
For Identity matrix, see [this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)

[Here's](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm) another page which gives you the matrices you would need to make **W**.

In the question above, you should take translation in x axis as 50, translation in y axis as 50, no scaling in either axis, and a rotation you haven't specified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually don't understand much of this. Not very good with math. With is a matrix? What do you mean by 'rotation, scaling and translation matrices'?

Comment: A [Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) is a very compact way of representing a set of interrelated numbers or objects. In Computer graphics, they are used extensively to make calculations. check the last link in the answer to know what I mean by Rotation translation and Scaling matrices.yes, you'll have to read all that. Otherwise you can use ashes999's method to solve your problem, but that won;t account for rotation and scaling of EntityA , if there is.

Answer (score 9):

I've done this with trigonometry rather than matrixes in the past (I am a matrix noob). Ashes999's answer is halfway there, get the relative vector, then rotate that by the inverse of EntityA's angle.

```
   relativeX = B.x - A.x
   relativeY = B.y - A.y
   rotatedX = Cos(-Angle) * relativeX - Sin(-Angle) * relativeY
   rotatedY = Cos(-Angle) * relativeY + Sin(-Angle) * relativeX
```

Comment: +1 Much more intuitive and easier to use trigonometry than matrixes.

Comment: What about the scale? When do you apply it?

Comment: Sorry, meant rotation.

Answer (score 7):

Let me try to give you something somewhere between The Light Spark's answer and Elliot's answer, because from what I read, you're really looking for an algorithm to follow and not just math tossed at you.

Problem Statement: Given that you have a location `A (50, 50)` and a heading (since you didn't provide one, I'll assert it as `y = 2 * x + 25`), find where `B (80, 90)` is relative to `A` and the heading.

What you want to do is actually fairly straightforward. 
1) Relocate `A` to the origin of your system. This is simply means that the local-to-`A` values are going to be the global position values minus the global position values of `A`. `A` becomes `(0, 0)` and `B` becomes `(30, 40)`.

1.1) The heading also needs to be moved. This is a actually very easy to do, because the y-intercept in local-to-`A` terms is always 0, and the slope won't change, so we have `y = 2 * x` as the heading.

2) Now we need to align the prior heading to the X axis. So, how do we do this? The easiest way, conceptually to do this is to convert from x, y co-ordinates to a polar co-ordinate system. Polar co-ordinate system involves `R`, the distance to a location, and `phi`, an angle of rotation from the x-axis. `R` is defined as `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` and `phi` is defined as `atan(y / x)`. Most computer languages these days go ahead and define a `atan2(y, x)` function which does the exact same thing as `atan(y/x)` but does so in such a way that the output tends to be from -180 degrees to 180 degrees rather than 0 degrees to 360 degrees, but either work.

`B` thus becomes `R = sqrt(30^2 + 40^2) = sqrt(2500) = 50`, and `phi = atan2(40, 30) = 53.13` in degrees.

Similarly, the heading now changes. This is a bit tricky to explain, but it because the heading, by definition, always passes through our origin `A`, we don't need to be worried about the `R` component. Headings are always going to be in the form of `phi = C` where `C` is a constant. In this case, `phi = atan(2 * x / x) = atan(2) = 63.435` degrees.

Now, we can rotate the system to move the heading to the X-axis of the local-to-`A` system. Much like when we moved `A` to the origin of the system, all we have to do is subtract the `phi` of the heading from all `phi` values in the system. So the `phi` of `B` becomes `53.13 - 63.435 = -10.305` degrees.

Finally, we have to convert back out of polar co-ordinates into x, y co-ordinates. The formula to do that transformation are `X = R * cos(phi)` and  `Y = R * sin(phi)`. For `B` therefore, we get `X = 50 * cos(-10.305) = 49.2` and `Y = 50 * sin(-10.305) = 8.9`, so `B` in local-to-`A` co-ordinates is close to `(49,9)`.

Hopefully that helps, and is light enough on the math for you to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the pose of Entity A in the global space \$(x_1, y_1, \theta)\$, where \$\theta\$ is the orientation relative to the x axis.

To convert the EntityB location from a global coordinate \$(x_2, y_2)\$ to a local coordinate \$(x_2',y_2')\$:

### 1. Using expressions

**Global to Local**

$$
\begin{align}
x_2' &= (x_2 - x_1) \cos \theta + (y_2 - y_1) \sin \theta \\
y_2' &= -(x_2 - x_1) \sin \theta + (y_2 - y_1) \cos \theta
\end{align}
$$

**Local to Global**

$$
\begin{align}
x_2 &= x_2' \cos \theta - y_2' \sin \theta + x_1 \\
y_2 &= x_2' \sin \theta + y_2' \cos \theta + y_1
\end{align}
$$

### 2. Using matrices

$$
\begin{align}
R &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix} \\
\vec A &= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\vec B_{global} &= \begin{pmatrix} x_2 & y_2 \end{pmatrix} \\
\vec B_{local} &= \begin{pmatrix} x_2' & y_2' \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

**Global to Local**

$$
\vec B_{local} = R^{-1} \times (\vec B_{global} - \vec A)
$$

(where \$R^{-1}\$ is the inverse of the matrix R)

**Local to Global**

$$
\vec B_{global} = R \times \vec B_{local} + \vec A
$$

Answer (score -2):

To put it simply entity B would need a reference to entity A. You'd then need to get the difference between entity's A position and entity B's position.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.