# Converting from global coordinates to local coordinates

Tags: c#, 2d, wpf

I am trying to create a Radar/Minimap for the F1 2021 game in C#/WPF. Here is a image of what I am trying to replicate

[image: radar]

In the image, the white car (my car) will always face the direction it is going. The blue car (other play car) will face relative to my direction.

I am given the following information

```
public float m_worldPositionX;           // World space X position
public float m_worldPositionY;           // World space Y position
public float m_worldPositionZ;           // World space Z position
public float m_worldVelocityX;           // Velocity in world space X
public float m_worldVelocityY;           // Velocity in world space Y
public float m_worldVelocityZ;           // Velocity in world space Z
public short m_worldForwardDirX;         // World space forward X direction (normalised)
public short m_worldForwardDirY;         // World space forward Y direction (normalised)
public short m_worldForwardDirZ;         // World space forward Z direction (normalised)
public short m_worldRightDirX;           // World space right X direction (normalised)
public short m_worldRightDirY;           // World space right Y direction (normalised)
public short m_worldRightDirZ;           // World space right Z direction (normalised)
public float m_gForceLateral;            // Lateral G-Force component
public float m_gForceLongitudinal;       // Longitudinal G-Force component
public float m_gForceVertical;           // Vertical G-Force component
public float m_yaw;                      // Yaw angle in radians
public float m_pitch;                    // Pitch angle in radians
public float m_roll;                     // Roll angle in radians
```

I am having trouble understanding the concept of worldForwardDir and worldRightDir, and how they differ.

Furthermore, I am wondering if it is even possible at all given the information above that I can transform the worldPosition coordinates into something usable by a 2D canvas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133205/discussion-on-question-by-ryan-converting-from-global-coordinates-to-local-coord).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `m_worldForwardDirX/Y/Z` is a unit vector pointing forward from the white car in world coordinates, and `m_worldRightDirX/Y/Z` is a unit vector pointing right.

If you take the position of the blue car and subtract the position of the white car, you have a difference vector in world coordinates. If you project this vector on `m_worldRightDir` you get the relative x coordinate of the blue car, and if you project it on `m_worldForwardDir` you get the y coordinate. These x and y coordinates are the x and y of the blue car in your radar view.

Projecting a vector on another vector is done by taking the dot product of the two vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway! I actually solved it without using the worldForwardDirX/Y/Z. Although I'm sure there are 100 ways of solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. Based off of Elliot's answer from this post [How do I convert from the global coordinate space to a local space?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79765/how-do-i-convert-from-the-global-coordinate-space-to-a-local-space)

```
var deltaX = Car.m_worldPositionX - PlayerCar.m_worldPositionX;
var deltaZ = Car.m_worldPositionZ - PlayerCar.m_worldPositionZ;
double deltaYaw = Car.m_yaw - PlayerCar.m_yaw;

var radius = Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaZ * deltaZ);
var phi1 = Math.Atan2(deltaZ, deltaX);
var phi2 = -PlayerCar.m_yaw;

var deltaPhi = phi1 - phi2;

var X = -(radius * Math.Cos(deltaPhi));
var Y = -(radius * Math.Sin(deltaPhi));
```